# AngularJS & TinyMCE conflict

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

For my app i using Angular-Ui TinyMce ([gitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce)).
I need catch click event in tinyMCE window. I initializate tinyMCE by:

> ```
> <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="activeArticle.content"></textarea>
> ```

But standard method:

> ```
> ed.on('click',function(e){
>     console.log(e);
>     e.preventDefault();
> });
> ```

don't calling. I think this is due to AngularJS catch click event and not propogate it to tinyMCE window. How i can stop AngularJS's click-catching for tinyMCE window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Angular-Ui TinyMce` doesn't manage click event. You need to complete [this directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/blob/master/src/tinymce.js) or add a function on you instance of TinyMCE like this :

```
editor.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
   // call angular function
   angular.element(document.getElementById('YourCtrl')).scope().yourFunction();
});
```